# Mobfox interstitial not showing

Tags: android, admob, mobfox

I configured the Mobfox SDK with its own functions and use Admob mediation to requests ads. The problem is that the requests are done (I can see them in Admob) but they are not shown (I do not have impressions). What could it happen?

Btw, of course, when an ad is loaded, it is shown. 
Admob interstitials are working right, but not Mobfox's ones.

Thank you all.

Comment: have u configure now are before google admob has updated now his service

Comment: New Google Play services is set and working ;)

Comment: have u create id today or before a day

Comment: 1 set 2014 admob has updated his service please check admob have u admob account

Comment: Admob and GPServices are both working. I check this before trying to do anything with Mobfox.

Comment: Create new id and check

Comment: Mobfox's ID alone was also working because I tested it. I guess the problem should be in the code to mix both kind of ads.